# Cannot open sever.jar file

Tags: java, macos, minecraft

So I was trying to make a 1.17.1 minecraft server on my mac. I couldn't open my 1.17.1_server.jar with Java 8 so I download Java 16.0.2.

Unfortunately, everytime I was opening the 1.17.1_server.jar file, I got
"The Java JAR file "1.17._server.jar" could not be launched." .

[image: error image]

I first thought that it was because the file was launch by Java 8 instead of 16.
So I went into the terminal and run :`<path to java> -jar 1.17.1_server.jar`

I then got this : `Error: Unable to access jarfile 1.17.1_server.jar`

Finally i tried to put the path of the jar file in the command...
So I've run : path to java -jar path to server
and got this :

```
[main/ERROR]: Failed to load properties from file: server.properties

[15:57:35] [main/WARN]: Failed to load eula.txt

[15:57:35] [main/INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.
```

So why I have to agreed Eula if i've never launched it ? Does it think that he already been launched ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message
[15:57:35] [main/INFO]: You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.

You have to open the file and check yes

Comment: okay but there's no eula.txt because i never succeed to launch the jar file

Answer (score 0):

Okay find the solution: my eula and server properties file were in my user folder dk why (never moved them so...)

Comment: okay so i've accepted the eula but still can't open it normally i have to use the console

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.